# Weird transform-style behavior in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d

I made this 3D model of a WWII plane. It's supposed to rotate, shoot and fly around.

[3D WWII Plane](http://codepen.io/vahidseo/full/vbwDI)

The problem is that Firefox doesn't render the plane like a 3D object, but Chrome does. Maybe the problem is my transform-style.

What do you think causes this problem? How do I fix it? And it's lagging a lot sometimes. How do I fix that?

Comment: Not all the browsers render same graphics. Firefox works differently compared to chrome.

Comment: @niranth-reddy Yeah, I got that part myself. But since there are standards, I was looking for a way to fix it, so that it looks 3D in Firefox too.

Comment: not carefully looked at it, just thought the problem was at the ***front fan***, but looks like it is more problematic than just that. My advice is just don't support FireFox, it sucks really much. It's a waste of time trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well again the so called ***FireFox*** proves that it's a buggy browser (not mentioning the slow feature it has). Looks like the whole model `.plane` can't apply the `transform-style:preserve-3d` down to all its descendants, just direct children or maybe that rule is applied only to pseudo-elements (`:before` and `:after`). In this case the front fan (`.body:after`) is not applied by the `preserve-3d` transform-style set in the model `.plane`, you have to set that style right in the `.body` (which is the direct parent of the fan `:after`), then it works just fine, of course the rendering is slightly different, which is caused by FireFox):

```
.plane > .body {
   /*...*/
   /* add this here */
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
/* do the same for other components having pseudo-elements */
.plane > .wings {
  /*...*/
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;      
} 
.plane > .ins {
  /*...*/
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;     
}   
.plane > .rear { 
  /*...*/
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;      
}
```

### [Updated demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lvItB).

Comment: @vahidseo what version of FireFox are you using? I've just tried it on the latest version of FireFox (30) and it works on my side, the front fan has a 3D look.

Comment: @king-kong I always keep my browsers up to date, do mine is the latest version too. Well, I meant the whole plane. That rotating illusion makes it look 3D, but actually it's rendered as 2D. If you visit that page via Chrome and right click on the plane, you'll see that it's actually a 3D plane.

Comment: @vahidseo the solution is still what I pointed out, but you have to do the same for all other components (which have pseudo-elements), see the updated answer, it should work now.

Comment: Now, that's something. Thanks, buddy.